# button width css transition doesn't work

Tags: css, button, css-transitions

I'm having a issue with a transition css property in a button tag.

When I hover the button I supposed it will go smoothly to width:auto, but it jump directly.

This is the code, what did I miss?

```
<button>Hello</button>

button {
   padding: 10px;
   width: 30px;
   overflow:hidden;
   transition: width 400ms ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: width 400ms ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
   width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max-width is your friend

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eukaw18t/2/)

```
button {
   padding: 10px;
   width: auto;
   max-width: 30px;
   overflow:hidden;
   transition: max-width 400ms ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: max-width 400ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: max-width 400ms ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this is really the same as setting a width value with pixels, ems, or as a percentage.

Comment: That looks beautiful, but still a little bit of delay between the hover and the response of the browser, don't you think? Thank you very much.

Comment: There's a reason for that - max-width extends to the edge of its parent so on mouseout it doesn't appear to reat instantly. It may not do this in practice, depending on how your layout is, and you could set max-width to a known max value.

Answer (score 1):

Transition won't work with `width: auto;` you have to give a value in px, ems, percentage or whatever...